# Link object files to binary file

Tags: c, assembly, linker

I want to link two object files to a binary file. I want that this binary file cotains only what I've written. When I use gcc it creates a 4kb file with lots of stuff I don't want. How can I create a binary file only containing my code? My second question is, what gcc links to my files?

Comment: What stuff does it create that you don't want?

Comment: Are you saying you want your binary file to be smaller?

Comment: @sharth I now checked the files with a hex editor. the file is zerofilled. My first file is at 0x0000 my second at 0x1000. Is it possible to insert my second file immediately after the first one and not zerofill up to 8kb?

Comment: @Jim I want it to contain only necessary stuff(my code).

Comment: Maybe use dynamically linked libraries?  Then the binary doesn't contain the library stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using 'gcc' to link the object files, consider using 'ar' command.  For example, you can use the following to create a static link library using 'ar':

```
$ ar cru libhello.a hello.o foo.o
```